# Postfix cannot connect to MySQL server for auth

Tags: mysql, postfix, authentication

I've got a mailserver with Postfix, Dovecot, `saslauthd` and a MySQL storage and auth backend. I can send emails just fine, however receiving emails (from Outlook in this case) fails with messages in `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`:

The MySQL log shows these errors:

```
53 Connect   mail@localhost on mail
53 Connect   Access denied for user 'mail'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
54 Connect   mail@localhost on mail
54 Connect   Access denied for user 'mail'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
55 Connect   mail@localhost on mail
55 Connect   Access denied for user 'mail'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
56 Connect   mail@localhost on mail
56 Connect   Access denied for user 'mail'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It appears I can't log in to the MySQL server, *however*, when I do

```
mysql -u mail -p -h localhost
```

I can log in *fine*. The password is known to be correct in both cases.

I have a feeling that this is all caused by Postfix (and subsequently SMTPD I think?) being run in a `chroot` jail in `/var/spool/postfix`. I've tried [disabling chroot](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#no_chroot) and mounting `mysql.sock` to a folder in the Postfic chroot, however nothing changes.

I've also tried changing instances of `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` and vice versa to no avail. Google has been sapped dry by my attempts to find a solution. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

What do I need to do to allow Postfix to access a MySQL database running on the same server? I want to use MySQL for other things like PHP, so a Postfix-exclusive solution isn't really an option. This has been troubling me for a good 3 days now and I've attempted all the solutions out there.

My `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` looks like this:

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
log_level: 7
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: localhost
sql_user: mail
sql_passwd: [hidden]
sql_database: mail
sql_select: select password from mailbox where username='%u@%r' and active = 1
```

I'm unsure what other files to post, so please comment and I will update accordingly. I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.10 32 bit.

Comment: Does your password have any non alphanumeric characters in it? I've had some strange issues with that, they worked from the command line, but it just wouldn't connect in any other manner.. getting rid of those odd characters solved the issue.

Comment: The password only consists of lowercase, uppercase and numbers, so I can't apply that nice simple fix `:(`

Comment: It's not anything like apparmor is it?

Comment: AppArmor isn't installed, so no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an utterly stupid mistake on my part. It turns out that in the config file `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf`, there was a space after the `sql_passwd` and other fields, meaning auth failed.

Comment: At least it works :)

Comment: Very true, but now I've got more problems (beyond the scope of my original question)

Comment: What sort of issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue username/password correct but in my case, I had this query:

```
query = select 1 as found from users where email = '%u@%d' and enabled = true LIMIT 1;
```

The problem was the ending `;`.

I just removed and it worked

```
query = select 1 as found from users where email = '%u@%d' and enabled = true LIMIT 1
```

The error message could be changed to something more usefully.